# how to config parent module of multi-module maven project with some modules in svn

Tags: maven, svn, module

I am a beginner of maven. Simply, I have three modules in a web project: parent-module, web-module and service-module.

```
parent-module
  +----web-module
  |         +----pom.xml
  +----service-module
  |         +----pom.xml
  +----pom.xml
```

Usually, parent-module.pom.xml may like this:

```
<modules>
   <module>../web-module</module> 
   <module>../service-module</module>
</modules>
```

how can i config parent-module.pom.xml when service-module is in svn and I haven't checked out it.

Comment: Why is `parent-module` inside `web-module`?  Seems to be counter-intuitive.

Comment: sorry, it's my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You structure is wrong. Changing the folder structure makes your life easier.

```
+-- parent-module (pom.xml)
        +--- web-module (pom.xml)
        +--- service-module (pom.xml)
```

And best to put the above structure into SVN into trunk. This means you can checkout the trunk of your project and you will get the above structure in your working copy.
So the result is:

```
svn checkout URL/project/trunk workingcopy
```

will create the following into the `workgincopy` folder:

```
+-- (pom.xml)
        +--- web-module (pom.xml)
        +--- service-module (pom.xml)
```

Based on the above your parent module will look like this:

```
<project>
  <groupId>whatEver</groupId>
  <artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  ...
  <modules>
     <module>web-module</module> 
     <module>service-module</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

Now your childs (web-module) look like this:

```
<project>
  <parent>
    <groupId>whatEver</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>web-module</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>whatEver</groupId>
      <artifactId>service-module</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
...
</project>
```

And finally your service-module looks like this:

```
<project>
  <parent>
    <groupId>whatEver</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>service-module</artifactId>

...
</project>
```

So in Maven you can change to root of your project (working copy) and build the whole project via the following:

```
mvn clean package
```

Comment: thx, but my situation is that if I have parent-module and web-module in localhost, and service-module in svn, then parent-module pom.xml whose <module> tag like yours cannot deploy, since it says service-module doesn't exist. Must I check out the service-module?